# .NET compatible qr scanning devices

Tags: .net, qr-code, hardware-interface

Does a scanning device exist which allows easy communication with the .NET framework?

The scanning device needs to be:

1. Portable (so it should be able to store data within itself until connected to a pc)
2. Should be able to scan QR Codes, and display appropriate options on the built in screen of the device
3. Should have a programmable display which gives the user custom options after scanning in a QR code
4. Once connected to a computer, it should automatically make any changes to a networked database, based on the temporary data saved on the device which will depend on which qr codes have been scanned and which options the user selected after scanning a qr code.

I have used a .NET tag, because it is the language used by the environment I will be working in.

Comment: Do you want something connected to a computer?  One would think most anything USB-based with a sensible SDK or driver documentation could be used (it may be, that as with linear barcodes, the minimal solution is to function as a keyboard).  Or do you want something self-contained which can run .NET code or talk to a server which does?  If the latter, something running windows phone (or perhaps Android with mono?) might be a starting point.

Comment: Not sure.  what ever it is, it must operate without a physically connecting it to a computer because it needs to be portable, ideally making updates to the database in real-ish-time.  Worst case scenario would be to update the database as soon as a physical connection is established with a computer.

Comment: That's not very specific.  But it seems like your first question is if you want to use a "phone" (wifi/mobile network, camera-based scaning) or if you want to use something actually sold as a "scanner" (perhaps faster, more locked down, maybe harder to develop for).  Right now the question is a bit open ended to answer - you may do better web search shopping for possibilities and then evaluating their viability against your limitations. Where does the .NET requirement come from?  Server compatibility?  Developer comfort?  Management familiarity?

Comment: After having a think about it, I've updated the question to be more specific

Comment: This question does not really seem to be appropriate for Stackoverflow, as this is not a programming related question. With that said, the Motorola MC9190 with the 2D scanner would meet all the listed requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expensive, but the Cognex 9500 should do everything you want:

http://www.cognex.com/DPM-mobile-computer.aspx

It's basically a Windows PDA lashed to a barcode reader. You can write your own apps in .NET Compact Framework to run on the PDA, and there's a C# API if you want to use the scanner from a PC.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get an iPod touch. Even the smallest iPod touch can store more than enough data from scanning QR codes.
2. Write a small app using the zBar SDK (free; LGPL) http://zbar.sourceforge.net/
3. Wifi your data from the iPod to the PC - for example using http

I have created a prototype scanning QR codes, storing them locally and then pushing the data via WIFI into an Access database within a day. My app also pulls configuration data from the Access database controlling certain choices in the UI.

You are a couple $ 100 (for the iPod) and a day of work away from a prototype.

Comment: +1 You could obviously also use an Android or Windows Phone device for this.

Comment: Yes - you could use Android or Windows. But if you don't need the phone part an iPod touch will do it. Using a wide spread Apple product you'll get a homogeneous supply chain with long term support. What Windows or Android phone would you select that more or less guarantees you timely OS updates after 3+ years.

Comment: Yes, but remember you've got to buy a Mac as your development environment, and more than likely use Objective C as your language. Nothing wrong with that, but that's something to bear in mind if that's not your skillset.

Comment: True - but the dev hardware expense for a Mac is one time. Shipping special hardware (like Cognex 9500) adds to the per unit price.

Comment: +1 Good point. Which approach is best all depends on the environment, client, and application, I guess.